# /home partition not recognized

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, home-directory

I upgraded to 11.04 with a CDROM. After the installation my home is empty and my installed apps are lost.

Everything in /usr/bin etc. has been reset back to the initial state. My /home is on a separate partition and natty didn't recognize it.

How do I get my configuration back?

Comment: could you please post the contents of /etc/fstab

Answer (score 3):

When upgrading, you should always use the Upgrade Manager, not the CD. they work different.

The CD repackages all installed packages found (it deletes self-compiled soft). wipes out almost all folders and reinstalls all packages back. The upgrade Manager only upgrades the packages which have a new version

To restore your /home do this:

1. Execute in a terminal:

   `sudo blkid`

   And note down the `UUID` and `TYPE` of the partition containing your old `/home` (you can get more info executing `sudo fdisk -l`)
2. Execute:

   `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`

   and add a new line at the end with the following syntax:

   `UUID={UUID} /home           {TYPE}    defaults        0`

   Replacing {UUID} and {TYPE} with the respective data.

   **Be sure that there is no other line with the mount point `/home`, or they will conflict (if there is, comment it out using `#`)*
3. Reboot

Comment: I think my main error was, that i used the cd for upgrading. Damn, only because i want it fast :( 
thank you!