# I upgraded to 11.10 but my home partition is missing, how can I recover it?

Tags: 11.10, installation, upgrade, home-directory, data-recovery

When I installed Ubuntu 11.04, I created a separate home partition. I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10. In the installation screen The options were:

1. Erase Ubuntu 11.04 and reinstall
2. Upgrade Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10
3. Erase everything and reinstall
4. Something else

I chose the option called "Erase Ubuntu 11.04 and reinstall".

Now that installation has finished, I have logged in but everything is fresh, my home partition was ignored or not recognized. So Opps... I must have choosen the wrong installation type from the menu - Doh!

Luckily, there is a glimmer of hope because I can see the old home partition in nautilus complete with my old home data and i can see the partition in `sudo fdisk -l`.

How can I recover my old home partition so that the new 11.10 uses it and everything is back to normal?

Should I re-install but choose a different option? Or is there some command line fu I can use to get me back up and running?

Answer (score 4):

Aha, I found the answer here: [/home partition not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43899/home-partition-not-recognized/45438#45438)

Cut & paste for convenience:

To restore your /home do this:

**Note** This will mount over your current /home if it exists. To fix this enter a terminal and `sudo umount /home` this will display the root partition /home directory contents which you can then move to a temporary location. Reboot or remount your home partition and move the data into /home again

1. Execute in a terminal:

   `sudo blkid`

   And note down the UUID and TYPE of the partition containing your old `/home` (you can get more info executing `sudo fdisk -l`)
2. Execute:

   `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`

   and add a new line at the end with the following syntax:

   `UUID={UUID} /home {TYPE} defaults 0 2`

   Replacing {UUID} and {TYPE} with the respective data.

   **Be sure that there is no other line with the mount point /home, or they will conflict (if there is, comment it out using #)*
3. Reboot